# need to compare and find the missing constraints between two DB

Tags: oracle, constraints

i need to compare two DBs and find the differences in constraints in all the schemas i.e. the schemas are used for test purpose and the DB objects are same between them. How can i compare the constraints mismatch? Give some inputs

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

select 'MISS_IN_DB1',table_name,constraint_name, constraint_type from all_constraints where owner = 'DB2' and constraint_name not like 'SYS%' and table_name not like 'BIN$%'

minus
select 'MISS_IN_DB1',table_name,constraint_name, constraint_type from all_constraints where owner = 'DB1' and constraint_name not like 'SYS%' and table_name not like 'BIN$%'

UNION
select 'MISS_IN_DB2',table_name,constraint_name, constraint_type from all_constraints where owner = 'DB1' and constraint_name not like 'SYS%' and table_name not like 'BIN$%'

minus
select 'MISS_IN_DB2',table_name,constraint_name, constraint_type from all_constraints where owner = 'DB2' and constraint_name not like 'SYS%' and table_name not like 'BIN$%'
;